# How to setup Xdebug in a Microservice Architecture PHP application, where the backend is split in multiple project

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, xdebug, xdebug-3

I am working on a project, and my project structure look like :

**FrontEnd:
Application-1**

```
www/
├─ application-Frontend/
│  └─ composer.json
   └─ custom-classes/controller/views/model
       └─ MyClass.php
```

**Backend:(Laravel)
Application-1**

```
www/
├─ application-a/
│  └─ composer.json
   └─ custom-classes/
       └─ MyClass1.php
```

**Application-2**

```
│
├─ application-b/
│  └─ composer.json
   └─ custom-classes/
          └─ MyClass2.php
```

The frontend application call the backend program logics over http.
The main reason to use multi application architecture is because the library is improving and changing over time, so to make it future proof for the moment we are using this approach. (This cannot be changed)

Some programs from Application-2 (backend) is using programs from Application-1 (backend) and for that we are using a utility program which does the call to a program with the help of artisan. This works fine.

The main issue is with Xdebug. During the development process we can only debug to a point where we are making a call to another application program, after that the Xdebug doesn't work.

Is there any way to configure the Xdebug which can work with call to another project i.e multiple application call? Preferred IDE : NetBeans, PhpStorm, Eclipse.

If something is not clear please comment I will try to explain.

Comment: XDebug will run once per-process; so unless all of your applications come from the same process (OpenSwoole, or some other long-running PHP [monolith]), then there would be multiple debug sessions open at once.

Generally, I've not seen multiple debug sessions open against a single server, but that can happen too.

What is particularly not clear is if you are looking for a single debug session across multiple codebases; or if you just want an IDE to be able to listen for the debugger in multiple containers.